# How to get all devices in Network within Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

For around 8 hours now already I am trying to find a way so that I can receive all devices which are in the same network as I am. I've already found a few ways to do this, but all of them boil down to ping all IPs in the network. That wouldn't be a big problem if Unity allowed multithreading. Due to the fact that it does not / basically only allows IEnumerator I have the problem that I have to execute each ping after another which needs a lot of time in which you cant even use the GUI.

My current code looks like this:

```cs
public class AddressFinder {

    private List<Ping> pingers = new List<Ping>();
    private List<IPAddress> addresses = new List<IPAddress>();

    private int timeOut = 250;
    private int ttl = 5;
    private int instances;
    private MonoBehaviour m;

    public void Scan(MonoBehaviour mono, IPSegment ips, Action<List<IPAddress>> callback) {
        this.m = mono;
        m.StartCoroutine(ScanAsync(ips, callback)); // New Coroutine so the UI should not freeze
    }

    private IEnumerator ScanAsync(IPSegment ips, Action<List<IPAddress>> callback) {
        PingOptions po = new PingOptions(ttl, true);
        byte[] data = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("abababababababababababababababab");
        instances = 0;
        foreach(uint host in ips.Hosts()) {  // Iterate over all IPs in that network
            m.StartCoroutine(Send(IPHelper.ToIpString(host) // IP as String, data, po));
        }
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
        while(instances > 0) {
            yield return wait;
        }
        callback(addresses);
    }

    private IEnumerator Send(string ip, byte[] data, PingOptions po) {
        instances++;
        Ping p = new Ping();
        PingReply rep = p.Send(ip, timeOut, data, po);
        p.Dispose();
        if(rep.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            addresses.Add(IPAddress.Parse(ip));
        instances--;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
    }
}
```

This wcode will actually work but needs like 4 mins to test all 253 IPs in my network. Also the UI freezes during this time.

I also tried using the unity Ping which seemed very inconsistent and also did not work that well, cause it also needed much to long for 254 pings.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is or has another idea to get all devices in the network?

Comment: i don't know if there is a good way in c#, but can you create a c++ library and create a wrapper for unity? i'm not sure if that would work, but just a thought. There is probably a better solution within unity ;).

Comment: @nka_Zz Was thinking about library too but i cant imagine that there is no way n Unity... Esspecially because its possible in pure c# easly. The problem is just unity not allowing the async operation of Ping for some reason.

Comment: could this be helpful? https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/6oui3f/multithreading/ the answer from IncendiaryGames looks helpful

Comment: i will have a look at it tomorrow i realy have to go to sleep. But as far as i have seen its about multi threading. My problem is yet, that for some reason `new Ping().SendAsync(...` does freeze unity ;(

Comment: Unity actually has its own [`Ping`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ping.html) implementation you could use in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: @derHugo as written in the Question I have tried it already but it is very unconsistent and also does not have a timeout which means you need to write that performant somehow your self. But yeah the biggest Problem is that it sometimes just does not reach the endpoint for no reason. I for example pinged my phone 1000 times with 7% not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way with threads. I actually thought one should not use threads in Unity but it seems to just not use Unity Operations outside of the main Thread, mean others are allowed. Anyways here is my Code:

```cs
using Ping = System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping;

public class AddressFinder {

    public List<string> addresses = new List<string>();
    private MonoBehaviour m;

    Thread myThread = null;
    public int instances = 0;

    public AddressFinder(MonoBehaviour mono) {
        m = mono;
    }

    public void Scan(List<IPSegment> iPSegments, Action<List<string>> addresses) {
        myThread = new Thread(() => ScanThreads(iPSegments, addresses));
        myThread.Start();
    }

    private void ScanThreads(List<IPSegment> iPSegments, Action<List<string>> callback) {
        Ping myPing;
        PingReply reply;
        instances = 0;

        foreach(IPSegment ips in iPSegments) {
            foreach(uint hosta in ips.Hosts()) {
                string ip = IPHelper.ToIpString(hosta);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    myPing = new Ping();
                    instances++;
                    reply = myPing.Send(ip, 250);

                    if(reply.Status == IPStatus.Success) {
                        addresses.Add(ip);
                    }
                    instances--;
                }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        while(instances > 0) {
            if(i > 100)
                break;
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        callback(addresses);
    }
}
```

```cs
public class LobbyManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.Object[] Games;
    private List<string> localAddresses = new List<string>();
    private List<string> hostAddresses = new List<string>();
    private Ping p;
    AddressFinder af;

    public void Start() {
        List<IPSegment> iPSegments = GetInterfaces(true);
        af = new AddressFinder(this);
        af.Scan(
            iPSegments,
            (addresses) => {
                localAddresses = addresses;
                foreach(string address in localAddresses) {
                    Debug.Log(address.ToString());
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public void Update() {

    }

    public List<IPSegment> GetInterfaces(bool showVPN) {
        List<IPSegment> ipsList = new List<IPSegment>();
        foreach(NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) {
            if(ni.Name.Contains("VM") || ni.Name.Contains("Loopback"))
                continue;
            if(!showVPN && ni.Name.Contains("VPN"))
                continue;
            foreach(UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses) {
                if(ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
                    IPSegment ips = new IPSegment(ip.Address.ToString(), ip.IPv4Mask.ToString());
                    ipsList.Add(ips);
                }
            }
        }
        return ipsList;
    }
}
```

**IPSegment** is a class where all IPs in this segment according to the subnetmask are saved in.

This code works kinda well but is not that performent which means that there should not be a higher Subnetmask than 255.255.255.0 or it will need ages.

Comment: Why should you not be allowed to use threads in Unity? It is c# so you can use what ever c# offers ;) be careful however to pass/dispatch the results back into the main thread otherwise you might get errors later from the Unity API ;)

Comment: @derHugo yeah we just learned Unity is not Thread safe and we were told to not use threads in Unity. As far as I found out yet, you should just not use operations of MonoBehaviour inside the threads but can do everything else in threads other than the main thread. Not sure if this is 100% correct.

Comment: @derHugo Cause you said you can use everythng C# offers. Am I right that you can only use .NET Framework and not .NET Core or did I mix something up?

Comment: You can do a lot more in threads ;) Basically all basic stuff also of the Unity API e.g. Vector and Quaternion operations etc. But yes basically everything that would directly influence your scene (changing materials, instantiate, move, etc) is only allowed to be used from the Unity main thread -> If you want to use your ping results somehow in your scene (otherwise why collect that info at all?) you have to make sure somehow to only do these calls in the main thread e.g. using a `ConcurrentQueue<Action>` that is worked of in `Update` somewhere ;)

Comment: And yes of course you can only use the stuff offered by the according c# version ;) And Unity is using .Net Framework 4.x (where afaik the x currently actually is 6.2 but nor sure on that one)

Comment: @derHugo Ah okay thanks for that info. I would have used an if in Update where it looks if the callback has finished and if so starts the task.

Comment: Exactly also fine of course! Depends on your needs. It is just important that you do your stuff somewhere within the `Update` (or other Unity thread based) message routine

Comment: @derHugo KK thanks for the infos learned much about threads in Unity now which I did not know yet :D